# Facebook Pixel Custom Dimensions Only Appearing on First Pageview

Tags: analytics, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

We have a single page Angular app with the Facebook pixel that is injected via GTM. In the first injection, we pass the following:

```
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '<OUR ID>'); // Insert your pixel ID here. 
</script>
```

Note, there is no pageview event. We then push a custom "virtual pageview" event to the GTM datalayer that leads to a tag that sends the pageview to Google Analytics (working fine), and triggers an injection of the following code as well:

```
<script>
fbq('track', 'PageView', {
    dim1:{{dim 1 macro}},
    dim2:{{dim 2 macro}},
    dim3:{{dim 2 macro}} 
});
</script>
```

On EACH pageview, the above fbq is appended to the DOM with the proper dimensions populated (by viewing the source of the page).

On the FIRST pageview HIT to Facebook, the dimensions are present in the call (by viewing the network tab), but on the SUBSEQUENT pageviews, a hit is sent to Facebook, BUT no dimensions are sent, even though they are present in the code appended to the DOM.

For the most part, these dimensions do not change hit to hit, but could change based on the actions the user does throughout their sessions.

Any thoughts as to why the subsequent hits DO NOT include the custom dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Received feedback from the official Facebook team, it seems that this is by design. On any subsequent call with a Pageview event, no custom data will be sent in the payload.

Comment: Does this mean the custom data is only passed on the first PageView event for a given page or only passed on the first PageView event for a visitor on a given website?

Comment: @RonC, at the time of the feedback, it was that the custom data is only passed on the first PageView event per given page (the former)

Comment: That clarification helps.

Answer (score 0):

You try to update a payload every time a history change happens in an Angular app and execute the fb code again with the updated payload?

I would implement a datalayer on your front-end:

```
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({
  event: 'virtualPageView',
  pagePath: '/newPath', //update this path from your angular route,
                        //or use GTMs built in history-change trigger
                        //and a variable that gets the URL fragment
                        //to update your pageview's path variable.
  customDimenson1: 'value1',
  customDimenson2: 'value2',
  customDimenson3: 'value3'
});
</script>
```

Create a trigger of the type *Custom Event* with the name *virtualPageView*.
Create 4 variables of the type *Data Layer Variable*, for *pagePath*, *customDimension1-3*.
Create your Custom HTML Tag which contains your fbq event:

```
<script>
fbq('track', 'PageView', {
    dim1:{{customDimenson1}},
    dim2:{{customDimenson2}},
    dim3:{{customDimenson3}} 
});
</script>
```

Create another *Custom HTML* Tag that fires on the built-in trigger *All Pages*, as it only needs to be executed once for your Single Page Application, with your base code:

```
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '<OUR ID>'); // Insert your pixel ID here. 
</script>
```

I had problems with SPA for updated variables. Sometimes it's a race condition, sometimes it's bugs in GTM or your code. You can also try to delay the execution by using a 100ms timer (bad advice).

Comment: Hi Underlines, this is how I have already implemented, and as I noted, the FIRST call works perfectly and includes the custom dimensions. On any subsequent calls, no dimensions are included, but the hit still does go to FB. The same tag that creates the first call also makes the second call

Comment: I see. Your original question was very brief, so I thought maybe you missed some steps. I remember having similar problems with blacksocks.com which moved to a SPA page. Had lots of non-updating variables and other problems. I would have to really digg deep into the GTM setup to find out more.Usually pushing events including an event key-value should be enough to update anything attached to it.

Comment: I'm kind of late to the party. I couldn't find any official documentation for being able to breakdown by custom dimensions. Can you refer to such docs?